# How to install ASP MVC 4 application inside ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, coreclr

I'm trying to migrate my old static website to ASP.NET core. In my old website, an ASP MVC 4 app lived inside the site.

- Main site: http://mysite.is-a-geek.com
- MVC4 app: http://mysite.is-a-geek.com/users

Now my ASP.MVC 4 application lives inside the ASP.NET core application, as the following image describes:

[image]

I need to manage all the routes in the ASP MVC 4 app independently. So the main ASP.NET Core application must bypass all routes under the directory `/users` so these requests are processed by the MVC 4 (users) application.

I usually manage these cases as follows:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("/users/{*pathInfo}");
```

But now, seems that **I cannot ignore routes in ASP.NET Core**.

I tried to configure the [static files](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html), but it did not worked:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.is-a-geek.com\users"),
        RequestPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/users")
    });
}
```

Do you know how could I manage this situation?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core sites are running under new webserver `Kestrel`. IIS simply redirects all requests to localhost:5000, that's why you need [special `web.config`](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html#working-with-iis) for running ASP.NET Core websites under (actually behind) IIS.

So, you should not try to configure ASP.NET Core to deal with your "/users" folder (it's too "late") - you should try to configure IIS do NOT redirect requests to that folder to kestrel webserver at all.

AFAIK, there is no possibility to configure different http handlers (for different subdirectories) in one (root) `web.config` file, so you can't mix old and new ASP.NET projects in one IIS website.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly agree with Dmitry's response but have more to add. I'd have put it as a comment but it's too long.

It is possible to configure IIS to use different handlers for different directories.  I'm unclear how that plays with ASP.NET Core, but from a pure IIS perspective you can route the requests to the handler of your choosing.  So for example, in my web.config in the `<system.webServer>`  `<handlers>` section I use these two lines to route requests for .js and .css files in the /bundle/ directory to the static file handler which causes such requests to enter the integrated pipeline where I can access them via code:

```
<add name="js-files--use-integrated-pipeline" path="/bundle/*.js" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
<add name="css-files--use-integrated-pipeline" path="/bundle/*.css" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
```

by contrast, I happen to to have all html files route to a different handler:

```
<add name="html-files--use-integrated-pipeline" path="*.html" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
```

It's probably also worth mentioning that even though ASP.NET Core does not use the web.config for general configuration information, there is still a web.config at the root of the webite which is used for configuring IIS.

Hopefully this information may be helpful for you to work out a solution.